# Create dynamic dockable window in WPF

Tags: wpf, dockable-windows

I have created an application which has one window. Click of a button in this window should open another dockable window. Is there a simple way to do this? I found a CodeProject which does this, but this seems a lot of functionality for me.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140209/Building-a-Docking-Window-Management-Solution-in-W

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/) ?

Here's the NuGet: http://www.nuget.org/packages/AvalonDock/